# how can I build my database for learning a network in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have some images that have been attacked with different kind of attacks like JPEG، salt & pepper,... now, I want to design a network that is fed with these images and their label and said what kind of attacks is done. but I do not know how can I make my database and prepare my training data? could you please help me with this issue? thanks in advance.
    I used the below code but It produces the following error and I do not know how can I solve this problem. please guide me about this issue.
I add this code but when I implement it, it produces this error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_37_input to have shape (512, 512, 1) but got array with shape (512, 512, 3)
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    import keras
    from keras import backend as K
    #K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3),border_mode='same', input_shape = (512, 512, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'rmsprop',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'E:\PhD\thesis\deepwatermark\databasetest\train',
        target_size=(512, 512),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'E:\PhD\thesis\deepwatermark\databasetest\validation',
        target_size=(512, 512),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=20,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=8)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of handling datasets, in keras you can feed the network with a numpy array or a generator.

Detailed documentation on generators :

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-methods

If you are going to use generators, before you do anything, separate your images by their labels into different directories. File hierarchy should look like

- TrainingData
- - Label1
- - - image1.jpg
- - - image2.jpg
- - Label2
- - - image1.jpg
- - - image2.jpg

If you are going to store all your data into a numpy array, I suggest putting all your data into a csv file and their labels should be the first or last column. I don't recommend this for big datasets since you may have not enough memory for all of your data.

Sample:
    model = 
    # Create preprocessor for train(map 0-255 rgb values to 0-1 , randomly zoom, 
    shear and flip to artificially increase data-size )
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

```
#Create validation preprocessor(map 0-255 rgb values to 0-1)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#Create train generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')
#Create validation generator
validation_generator = 
    validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')
#fit your model using the data from generators.
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800)
```

Comment: thank you for the response. can the labels folder name be the name of attacks or they should be numbers? I built my database as the mentioned example. but how should I feed them to the network? I am a beginner and I am not familiar with python.

Comment: I go to this link to see datagenerator example but I did not understand how can I feed my train data. due to in this example, he uses 3 samples but I have about 1000 samples for each class, so how can I create a dictionary that it contains a list of my train and test examples. could you please help me with this?
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Comment: Label folder's names should correspond to labels you are using in your network, here they are name of attacks. 

Example you showed implements generators, but you don't have to implement them, keras already have have api for this. 
 example on keras' documentation: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory

Comment: I am a little confused. can I only use this function and I will not need to do any processing on images? could you please explain more? I know these issues are simple but I am a beginner and they are a little difficult for me:(

Comment: Alright, 

If you use flow from directory function keras will go to the given path and then it will look at the directories inside. Number of directories is equal to number of classes, names of directories are names of classes. 

When you give this generator to your model, whenever your model requests a batch, generator will -yield- samples from these directories which has size equal to your batch size.

Comment: I add my code but it produces an error. could you please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using generators because they are easy to write and are safe for running your code. As for organizing the data, the answer from @Mete is ok, but consider also making a csv with image names in one column and type of attack in other. Then you just go through the csv file row by row, doing whatever you need to do with it then.